# Use python libraries in React Native

Tags: android, python, ios, react-native, mobile

I want to use some Python libraries (for machine learning etc) in a React Native app. 
Is it possible to do it without using a server (i.e. run the Python code within the mobile app) so that no internet is required?

Answer (score 7):

The React Native App consists of two major portions

- Business Logic which is a NodeJs app. This app controls the other piece
- Frontend which is written in Javascript, however it gets linked to native interfaces (Java in case of Android and Obj-C in case of iOS)

In this framework, best way to integrate **Python Code**, machine learning or otherwise is to connect NodeJS app with Python interpreter. This also happens to be complex to implement. This will go something like this

```
#include <Python.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                 "print 'Today is',ctime(time())\n");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

As seen at [Embedding Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html)

Now this is bit tricky so lets look at secondary options like connecting with the model using C++. Like [Tensorflow](http://amzn.to/2AEkr0P) also has a C++ API which can be used to integrate Models into NodeJS. Final option is ofcourse to use it as a separate child process or server side call.

Comment: I'm a bit late to this, but wouldn't spawning a child process be enough or something like [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) rather than having to embed it by hand? I'm not very familiar with node.js so I could be wrong here

Comment: @SSBakh, I'm VERY late too :-D , the OP states 'React-Native', so, that will most probably be a mobile environment, such as IOS or Android, neither of which has a Python interpreter installed. I assume you're thinking about a desktop installation, like Linux.

Personally, I might like to run some Python on mobile, cross-compilation is an idea (see Brython or Transcrypt), as it finding some kind of mobile embeddable version of Python, if such a thing were to exist.