# How to access python library in javascript react native library

Tags: javascript, python, react-native

I am developing a mobile application using the react native library with the JavaScript language. On the other hand, I have an image processing code that I wrote in python. Is it possible to combine them? Can I put python in my React native code?

Comment: may be it can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806024/use-python-libraries-in-react-native

Comment: why dont you buid a rest api and access them from js http calls ?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. What are you trying to achieve? Why do you thing that embedding python in your React native code is the way to achieve it?